Jwt Bearer token is invalid in ASP.NET Core Web API
I get: WWW-authenticate: Bearer error="Invalid_token"

HTTP 401 means the request wasn't made with any credentials - or with the incorrect scheme.

if you get back the token - then this code is working properly. the problem may be in how you create Postman request. I understand that you are frustrated - but the information here is quite useless for anybody to help you.

From my understanding you want to use jwt bearer together with the built-in identityUser tables.
The builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(...) actually creates another cookie authentication scheme by default and has been added to the authentication pipeline. So there will be some conflict with this "cookieScheme" and the "jwtScheme".
You could replace it with following:
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>(options=>...)
    //.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
...

By contrast, AddIdentityCore will not add addtional authentication schemes. So it avoid confict with "jwt"
